# Server side CURL POST request on button press

Tags: javascript, html, api, curl

I have some code which generates a token.

Currently I have to take the token and manually execute the POST request to communicate with the 3rd party endpoint and complete the action.

I would like to trigger this automatically on the press of the button.

I can write a curl command to execute the request but I am not sure I can embed that in my html page.

I know to place it in the script after receiving a successful token but then i imagine I need to store the token in a variable also so I can feed it into the curl command.

some help and guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Axios` or `Fetch` to post to the endpoint brom browser. You can store the token in memory or localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@ozgur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14521257/ozgur) comment with an example:

```js
// This will go in your <script> tag
// or wherever you JavaScript code is handling the button press

  fetch('http://example.com/movies', {
    method:'POST'
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('myCustomToken', data.token);
    // Can be access later like so:
    window.localStorage.getItem('myCustomToken');
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can see more examples and details about the [Fetch API in the Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: thanks @ayushya Do you know how I post the response on to the screen?

I just want to ensure that it works because I do not have access to the full API just yet

Comment: @redhood apologies for the delay - you can try simply logging it to the console `console.log(data);` If you use the log in the backend it'll show up in the server logs if not it'll show up in the developer pane of the browser.